# Is it acceptable to add a setup algorithm in the public key encryption?

Tags: encryption, public-key

I saw in the paper [How to Use a Short Basis: Trapdoors for Hard Lattices and New Cryptographic Constructions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/432.pdf) at page 29 that key generation algorithm of PKE can use a common random matrix $A$.

- Is it OK to add a setup algorithm that generates some common public parameters?

Comment: To get better answers you might consider expanding on why you considered it a potential problem.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

There are a lot of precedents, for example DSA of [FIPS 186-4](https://web.archive.org/web/20181226075209if_/https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) has a setup algorithm, described in appendix B.1.